# How to prevent navigation until all validation are fulfill?

Tags: android, forms, validation

I want to add validation to my form. But there is one problem I press submit button it shows the validation for a quick time, and blank form submitted to recyclerview. please give me the solution if you have.

Comment: Can you please add some of your code to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below validation method, if it's not working, please share your code here to look further more into your problem.

```
if (editTextName.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0 || 
   editTextAge.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0) {
     Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Fields should not be blank", 
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
   callSubmitFormApi();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    /**
     * Performs action to submit the form if all the validations are fulfilled
     */

    public void submitForm() {

        if (validateFields()) {
            //Todo add your form submission code here
        }
    }


    /**
     * Validate all the fields present in the form according to the requirements
     * Returns true if there is no validation error, false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean validateFields() {

        if (editTextEmail.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            //Show toast or snackbar for validation failed
            return false;
        } else if (//todo another validation code)
        {
        //Show toast or snackbar for validation failed
        return false;
    }
         return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go like this:

```
    public void clickAction(){

       if(validateFields()){
       //Todo add your form submission code here
       }
    }


    public boolean validateFields(){

        if(editTextEmail.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
            //Show toast validation failed
            return false;
        }else if(//todo another validation code){
            return false;
        }
         return true;
    }
```

Comment: I also write my code as your text, but when I click on submit it navigate in another activity.

Comment: It will not navigate until unless validate method returns true

Answer (score 0):

Performs action to submit the form if all the validations are fulfilled

```
public void submitForm() {

    if (validateInputFields()) {
        //Todo add your form submission code here
    }
}
```

Validate all the fields present in the form according to the requirements

Returns true if there is no validation error, false otherwise.

```
public boolean validateInputFields() {
   if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
     //Show toast or snackbar for validation failed
        return false;     
    }      
  else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
        //Show toast or snackbar for validation failed
        return false;
    }
  else if (//todo another validation code)
    {
    //Show toast or snackbar for validation failed
    return false;
    }
     return true;
```

}